# Get type of value of mapped type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

If there is type like

```
interface ParsedQs { [key: string]: undefined | string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[] }
```

How can I get the value of the type above? I want the following

```
type ParsedQsValue = undefined | string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[]
```

without explicitly copying the type from the `ParsedQs` definition.

Answer (score 1):

```js
type ParsedQsValue = ParsedQs[string]
```